# Does BIOS MBR limit linux distros installments?

Tags: partition, dual-boot, mbr

Long ago I've installed Windows 7 in legacy (BIOS) mode with MBR (why? who knows) and made 4 primary partitions, one for Windows and the others for files. Later I've changed one primary into logical and installed linux dualboot. I use GRUB2 to launch OS. And since then I've also got second HDD which doesn't have any OS on it.

Now I want to install another Linux distro.

The question: should I change another primary into logical and install linux2 in primary or I will be able to install linux2 as logical?

And if I want to install linux2 on second HDD, does it have it's own partition limit even if system is loading from first HDD? I mean if I install another linux on second HDD in primary partition, will it be fith primary partition and mess up everything?

Comment: The only time to use MBR(msdos), now, is if booting Windows in the old BIOS/MBR configuration. Most systems will boot from gpt drives. And with Linux you can boot in BIOS mode if you also have bios_grub partition or in newer UEFI mode with an ESP - efi system partition. I started to use gpt 10 years ago when system was only BIOS. Then started adding both ESP & bios_grub, so could easily convert drive to a newer UEFI system. Now only UEFI/gpt.  [gpt Advantages](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1457901) & 
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Partitioning#Choosing_between_GPT_and_MBR

Comment: @oldfred I know about that. But my system is using MBR. And to change that I will need to reinstall everything. It'll take too much time, I can't do it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Later I've changed one primary into logical and installed linux dualboot.

Primary would have been also good. I always used as many primary partitions as possible and if I needed more partitions, I changed the 4th primary into an extended partition with logical partitions inside.

> should I change another primary into logical and install linux2 in primary or I will be able to install linux2 as logical?

Choose what is more convenient for you.

> And if I want to install linux2 on second HDD, does it have it's own partition limit even if system is loading from first HDD?

It's the same (MBR) partition limit as for the first HDD. 4 primary partitions max. or 3 primary and one extended partition
with more than enough logical partitions (I honestly don't know the exact number).

> I mean if I install another linux on second HDD in primary partition, will it be fith primary partition and mess up everything?

It will be the first primary partition of the second disk. No problem.